# Android nested layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, nestedlayout

I am new to android layouts, Could please tell me how the performance of application when  using nested layouts instead of using layout below, layout above, layout right, layout left attributes of relative layout  for components.

For eg:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <scrollView>
       <RelativeLayout>
          <LinearLayout> Header<LinearLayout>
           <TextView/>  <TextView/>
           <TableLayout>
                   <TableRow><ImageView/> <TextView> <Spinner><TableRow>
                   <TableRow><ImageView/> <TextView> <Spinner><TableRow>
                   <TableRow><ImageView/> <TextView> <Spinner><TableRow>
                   <TableRow><ImageView/> <TextView> <Spinner><TableRow>
          </TableLayout>

          <TextView>
          <TableLayout>
                 <TableRow>
                    <LinearLayout> <ImageView><TextView></LinearLayout> 
                    <EditText>
                 </TableRow>
                 <TableRow>
                    <LinearLayout> <ImageView><TextView></LinearLayout>
                    <EditText>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                   <TextView> 
                   < Spinner>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow><TextView> <Spinner></TableRow>
          </TableLayout>

           <TableLayouts>---</TableLayout>

          <LinearLayout> footer</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks & Regards
Yamini

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well some layouts can only be made by doing some level of nesting. But you should avoid having too many nested LinearLayouts and even more important NEVER nest LinearLayouts with weights. You can read a little more about optimizing layouts in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html).

Personally I use LinearLayouts for simple stuff and start using RelativeLayout when the layout gets more complex. There is no one answer as it is a matter of preference.

Comment: This is particularly important in the case of lists where the views need to redrawn many times when scroll is done.

Answer (score 2):

Would highly recommend you a tool that's called Hierarchy Viewer. It's bundled with the SDK and you can find it under android-sdk/tools directory. In short, it helps find problems in your layouts by measuring time that takes them to be processed. A broader description of Hierarchy Viewer can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: now deprecated, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector is the equivalent tool to use