# Does using a lot of nested layouts make the app slower?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am working on a big application , and I have to use a lot of nested layouts especially LinearLayout . some times android studio warn me about using a lot of (weight) attribute , I am just wondering , does using a lot of nested layouts will make the application slower ?

Comment: Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15405309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, especially in the older devices with limited hardware capabilities. Take a look for instance at:

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Simpler layouts means less work to do in the UI thread in order to draw it therefore your app will be faster and more responsive.